# Short doors / method for low ceiling and ducting for finishing basement

Tags: ceiling, basement-refinishing

**Background**

We are in the process of planning to finish our basement. For most of the basement the ceiling to floor height is 83 inches making it pretty doable for most items.  The problem I am coming across is what to do for our planned bedroom closet.

**Layout**

[image]

The orange hash in the middle represents where the I-Beam and ducting runs. At this region the height is only 74 inches minimum.  Most doors are 80 inches so I could trim it down to fit but are there other better methods to make it not look so odd?

In the layout, the orange is what exists currently, red is the plan so far, so any red can be modified.

**My thoughts so far**

My original thought was to put two sliding closet doors just in front of the low spot so that I can put the slider mechanism, and trim boards above the I beam. I could adjust the front closet wall to position the I beam / ducting to be inside the closet but don't want to loose too much room space.

**Layout per feedback**

[image]

Comment: As you say, why not position the slider about 4" plan down so that it can be full height? Then when opened, the upper part will just be dry wall behind the door. Note, be sure to allow the 1/2" for this dry wall. Why not just eliminate the other door? It's an odd feature and feels forced due to your situation

Comment: @Ack Great thoughts! I updated the layout. I agree with you to eliminate the back door as I found it awkward too.. I think the sliding door 4 inches forward helps make the best of the situation.

Comment: You have two options: Shorten the door or move the wall. Did you have a more specific question?

Comment: Third option...a curtain.

Comment: I agree Eric F, that's pretty good. I would suggest thinking about filling in the ceiling at plan up of the closet so that it's the same height as the bottom of the ducting, that little space will look odd and be hard to finish with dry wall and mud. OR, you might get creative somehow with that space with some custom storage solutions, I don't have any ideas off the top of my head. You could put a short door there or as Steve Wellens noted, a curtain. Personally, I think a short door would have some character, especially if I found a special one